# py2app generates .app with no errors but .app crashes and quits unexpectedly

Tags: python, virtualenv, py2app, pulp

**RESOLVED**

If someone else runs into issues with this, I suggest to just try py2app without VirtualEnv and it should work perfectly!  This is the only solution I could come up with.

**Original Question**

I am trying to use py2app and it generates .app with no errors but .app crashes and quits unexpectedly.

I am trying to do this in virtualenv so I am not sure if that is an issue with all the paths. It works on my computer when all the virtual environments exist but as soon as I close them down, the .app no longer works.

The virtual environment I am using has python 2.7.5

Here is my setup.py:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myApp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'packages': ['pulp']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. are you using the python's brew environment?
then build the python's default setting, not the brew.